# throwing exception invalid IP and how to solve it with async task

Tags: android

I am following up this [tutorial](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php) on how to connect to php server and insert data however I got exception **invalid IP address** with red error on logcat:

```
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This my code that has IP:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://31.170.160.102/insert.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
```

Ofcourse I did a quick search and found this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028714/error-nullpointerexception-lock-null) , it says that to solve the problem I should use `Async`.

**So My questions:**
 Why I am having the exception invalid IP? With red error on logcat. 
If using `Async Task` should solve the problem, then where I have to added in my code?
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link should help you out:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask